# vue-test-utils: Vue child-component method "is not a function"

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

In this test, I am simply trying to assert that the `end` property is set on the component under test (`DateRangeEditor`). The component assumes `this.$refs.datepicker` is an instance of [`HotelDatepicker`](https://krystalcampioni.github.io/vue-hotel-datepicker/) and calls its `setCheckOut` and `setCheckIn` methods (if there is a better way to do this please let me know!).

The component works when loaded normally in the browser, but my test for `setEndDate` is failing with "TypeError: this.$refs.datepicker.setCheckIn is not a function".

**Am I misunderstanding what setting the `stubs` option is supposed to do?** I thought scenarios like this, where the calling code just needs to call the stubbed function and doesn't need a specific result, were exactly what stubs are for. Am I just using it wrong?

Here's my test:

```
import { mount, shallow } from 'vue-test-utils'
import DateRangeEditor from '../../assets/src/components/DateRangeEditor.vue'

describe('DateRangeEditor', () => {

  describe('@checkOutChanged', () => {
    it('sets a new end date', () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(DateRangeEditor, {
        stubs: ['datepicker']
      })

      // simulate user changing the end date
      const date = new Date(2017, 11, 1)
      wrapper.vm.$refs.datepicker.$emit('checkOutChanged', date)

      expect(wrapper.vm.end).to.equal(date)
    })
  })

  describe('@checkInChanged', () => {
    it('sets a new start date', () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(DateRangeEditor, {
        stubs: ['datepicker']
      })

      // simulate user changing the start date
      const date = new Date(2017, 11, 1)
      wrapper.vm.$refs.datepicker.$emit('checkInChanged', date)

      expect(wrapper.vm.start).to.equal(date)
    })
  })
})
```

And here is my (greatly simplified) `DateRangeEditor` component:

```
<template>
  <div class="date-range-editor-container">
    <datepicker
      @checkInChanged="setStartDate"
      @checkOutChanged="setEndDate"
      ref="datepicker"
    ></datepicker>
    <button type="button" @click="save" class="btn save-btn">Save</button>
    <button type="button" @click="cancel" class="btn cancel-btn">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HotelDatePicker from 'vue-hotel-datepicker'

export default {
  methods: {
    setStartDate: function(newDate) {
      if (newDate) {
        // make sure newDate has an hour component
        newDate.setHours((new Date()).getHours())
        this.$refs.datepicker.setCheckIn(newDate)
        this.start = newDate
      }
    },
    setEndDate: function(newDate) {
      if (newDate) {
        // make sure newDate has an hour component
        newDate.setHours((new Date()).getHours())
        this.$refs.datepicker.setCheckOut(newDate)
        this.end = newDate
      }
    },
    save: function() {
      this.$emit('save', this.$data)
    },
    cancel: function() {
      this.$emit('cancel', this.$data)
    },
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      start: '',
      end: '',
    }
  },
  components: {
    datepicker: HotelDatePicker,
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Finally, here's my setup.js bootstrap file:

```
/* globals global */
require('jsdom-global')()
const chai    = require('chai')
const sinon   = require('sinon')

// use Sinon test spies/stubs/mocks in all tests
chai.use(require('chai-sinon'))

// expose libs to all tests
global.chai     = chai
global.sinon    = sinon
global.expect   = chai.expect
```

### versions n stuff

- @vue/test-utils ^1.0.0-beta.10
- vue ^2.4.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stubs` replaces child component methods. This is why you're getting the error.

If you want to check that a method is being called, you can create a component with the methods and pass it in the `stubs` option.

```
const datepicker = {
    setCheckIn: () => {},
    setCheckOutDate: () => {},
    render: () => {}
}

it('sets a new end date', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(DateRangeEditor, {
    stubs: {
      datepicker
    }
  })

  const date = new Date(2017, 11, 1)
  wrapper.vm.$refs.datepicker.$emit('checkOutChanged', date)
  expect(wrapper.vm.end).to.equal(date)
})
```

Comment: Hi @Edd, thanks for your answer and for your work on Vue! Yeah, I tried that initially, but when I do that, I get "Error: [vue-test-utils]: options.stub values must be passed a string or component". And if I pass `mocks` instead, (everything else the same, essentially `s/stubs:/mocks:/`), I get the same `TypeError` as before.

Comment: I've updated my example to include a render function on the stub. At the moment, vue-test-utils needs a render function for the stub to valid (we'll fix this as it's not always the case). Try again with the example I added, it should work as expected 

Comment: That fixed it. Writing up a GH issue for that now, thanks!